# Turn data from PostgreSQL to JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, server

I have the following code:

```
    const result = await client.query("select pword from users where username like '" + ln + "';");
    console.log(result.rows)
```

which sends following to the terminal: [ { pword: '00' } ]

Is there a way for me to extract '00', and store it in a variable? I am using Node JS and Express.

Comment: `result[0].pword` ?

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by this

```
result.rows[0].pword
```

Answer (score 1):

The postgres query is returning an array. To access the contents of this array you are going to get the first index by doing result[0]. Next you are going to access the variable in the object nested by the array using dot notation. So your final will be result[0].pword

you can store this in a variable by doing

```
var foo = result[0].pword
```

it looks like you could use some information about arrays and how to use them. Here are some relevant docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp